# How to print this type of array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [3] => 

    [4] => 

    [5] => 

    [6] => 

    [7] => 

    [8] => 

    [9] => 

    [10] => 

    [11] => 

    [12] => 

    [13] => 

    [14] => 
)
```

How to print above array using foreach?I tried by using foreach like this:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($array as $arr)

{

    echo $arr[$i];

    $i++;

}
```

But the result is empty.

Comment: How would you like it to show on the page?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...etc

Comment: `echo` does not understand how to print an array. You could start with a `print_r($array)` or a `var_dump($array);`

Answer (score 1):

If the value is itself an array ( of potentially unknown length ) then you need to iterate through it also.

```
foreach( $array as $index => $val ){
    if( is_array( $val ) ){
        foreach( $val as $i => $arr ) echo $arr;
    } else {
        echo $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JithuJohnson: if this was a helpful answer, please consider accepting it. To do so, click on the tick mark to the left, so that it turns green.

Answer (score 0):

You can print with [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or using [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) - you're doing it wrong though!

```
print_r($array); //will print the whole array

var_dump($array); //will print the whole array plus variable type and length

foreach($array as $arr){
    //$arr is the array VALUE!
    if(!is_array($arr)) echo $arr;
        else echo $arr[0];
}
```

Comment: This will lead to `Array to string conversion` for the first three values of the outer array which are also arrays.

Comment: I tried as you said but it is showing arrayarrayarray

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value) && count($value) > 0) {
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $val1) {
            echo $val1;
        }
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function print_array($array){
    foreach ($array as $value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            print_array($value);
        }
        else{
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}

$array = array('a', 'b', array('c', 'd'));

print_array($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of imbricate array, the best way is recursivity :

```
function print_table($table){
    foreach ($table as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            print_table($value);
        } else {
            echo "<p> $key -> $value </p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Exemple

```
$fruits = array (
    "fruits"  => array("a" => "orange", "b" => array("a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"), "c" => "apple"),
    "numbers" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
    "holes"   => array("first", 5 => "second", "third")
);

print_table($fruits);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!